# How to exclude some slides from numeration, delete slide numbers and delete circles?

Tags: beamer

I would like to

(1) exclude the Appendix section from the numeration of the main slides

(2) hide the numbers at the bottom of the slides belonging to the Appendix section

(3) hide the circles at the top of the slides belonging to the Appendix section

How can I do it?

Here an example of my document: as suggested in the comments below I can reach (1) by including [noframenumbering]. However this does not solve (2), (3)

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\useinnertheme{circles}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}

\makeatletter
\newcount\beamer@subsectionstartframe
\beamer@subsectionstartframe=1
\apptocmd{\beamer@subsection}{\addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{%
            \protect\beamer@subsectionframes{\the\beamer@subsectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\beamer@subsection}{\beamer@subsectionstartframe=\c@framenumber\advance\beamer@subsectionstartframe by1\relax}{}{}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{nav}%
        {\noexpand\headcommand{\noexpand\beamer@subsectionframes{\the\beamer@subsectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}}{}{}
\def\beamer@startframeofsubsection{1}
\def\beamer@endframeofsubsection{1}
\def\beamer@subsectionframes#1#2{%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber<#1%
    \else%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber>#2%
    \else%
    \gdef\beamer@startframeofsubsection{#1}%
    \gdef\beamer@endframeofsubsection{#2}%
    \fi%
    \fi%
}
\newcommand\insertsubsectionstartframe{\beamer@startframeofsubsection}
\newcommand\insertsubsectionendframe{\beamer@endframeofsubsection}
\makeatother

\newcounter{subsectionframenumber}
\newcounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
            \parbox[b]{.4\textwidth}{
            \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead%
            \setcounter{subsectionframenumber}{1}
            \addtocounter{subsectionframenumber}{\insertframenumber}
            \addtocounter{subsectionframenumber}{-\insertsubsectionstartframe}
            \setcounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{1}
            \addtocounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{\insertsubsectionendframe}
            \addtocounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{-\insertsubsectionstartframe}
            \ifnum\thesection>0%
            \foreach\x in {1,...,\thetotalsubsectionframenumber}{%
                \ifnum\x=\thesubsectionframenumber%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}~%
                \else%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}~%
                \fi%
            }%
            \fi%
        }%
        %\hfill\hyperlink{toc}{Outline}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
    }
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\newcommand{\beginbackup}{
   \newcounter{framenumbervorappendix}
   \setcounter{framenumbervorappendix}{\value{framenumber}}
}
\newcommand{\backupend}{
   \addtocounter{framenumbervorappendix}{-\value{framenumber}}
   \addtocounter{framenumber}{\value{framenumbervorappendix}} 
}

\usepackage{multicol}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}


    \beginbackup
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    \backupend

    \begin{frame}[label=toc]
        \frametitle{Outline}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \section{BLAH}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \subsection{sub1}

    \begin{frame}{SLIDE1}\label{slide1}
    \hyperlink{appendix}{\beamergotobutton{More}}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{SLIDE2}
    \end{frame}


    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \section{Appendix}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{Extensions 1}\label{appendix} 
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{Extensions 2}
    \hyperlink{slide1}{\beamergotobutton{Back}}
    \end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at this package: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer-contrib/appendixnumberbeamer?lang=en

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I have just realised that it actually does not solve my problem. It does not match with the circles for each section.

Comment: A quick question: what's the purpose of the "appendix" around the title page? Just having it unnumbered? would `[noframenumbering]` also do?

Comment: By default stuff in the appendix isn't included in the outline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is getting a bit messy, seems to fulfil `(1)`-`(3)`. I also removed the frame numbers displayed on the titlepage, as you seem to want this unnumbered it became `0/3` and looked strange.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\useinnertheme{circles}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}

\makeatletter
\newcount\beamer@subsectionstartframe
\beamer@subsectionstartframe=1
\apptocmd{\beamer@subsection}{\addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{%
            \protect\beamer@subsectionframes{\the\beamer@subsectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\beamer@subsection}{\beamer@subsectionstartframe=\c@framenumber\advance\beamer@subsectionstartframe by1\relax}{}{}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{nav}%
        {\noexpand\headcommand{\noexpand\beamer@subsectionframes{\the\beamer@subsectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}}{}{}
\def\beamer@startframeofsubsection{1}
\def\beamer@endframeofsubsection{1}
\def\beamer@subsectionframes#1#2{%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber<#1%
    \else%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber>#2%
    \else%
    \gdef\beamer@startframeofsubsection{#1}%
    \gdef\beamer@endframeofsubsection{#2}%
    \fi%
    \fi%
}
\newcommand\insertsubsectionstartframe{\beamer@startframeofsubsection}
\newcommand\insertsubsectionendframe{\beamer@endframeofsubsection}
\makeatother

\newcounter{subsectionframenumber}
\newcounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
            \parbox[b]{.4\textwidth}{
            \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead%
            \setcounter{subsectionframenumber}{1}
            \addtocounter{subsectionframenumber}{\insertframenumber}
            \addtocounter{subsectionframenumber}{-\insertsubsectionstartframe}
            \setcounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{1}
            \addtocounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{\insertsubsectionendframe}
            \addtocounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{-\insertsubsectionstartframe}
            \ifnum\value{section}>0%
            \foreach\x in {1,...,\value{totalsubsectionframenumber}}{%
                \ifnum\x=\value{subsectionframenumber}%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}~%
                \else%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}~%
                \fi%
            }%
            \fi%
        }%
        %\hfill\hyperlink{toc}{Outline}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
    }
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\newcounter{framenumbervorappendix}

\usepackage{multicol}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

{

  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
%      \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
  } 

    \begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

}

    \begin{frame}[label=toc]
        \frametitle{Outline}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}

    \section{BLAH}
    \subsection{sub1}

    \begin{frame}{SLIDE1}\label{slide1}
    \hyperlink{appendix}{\beamergotobutton{More}}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{SLIDE2}
    \end{frame}


    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \setcounter{framenumbervorappendix}{\value{framenumber}}
    \section*{Appendix}
    \subsection{Appendix}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 {

 \setbeamertemplate{headline}
 {
     \leavevmode%
     \hbox{%
         \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
             \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
         \end{beamercolorbox}%
         \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
         \end{beamercolorbox}}%
         \vskip0pt%
     }   

  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
%      \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
  }   


    \begin{frame}{Extensions 1}\label{appendix} 
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{Extensions 2}
    \hyperlink{slide1}{\beamergotobutton{Back}}
    \end{frame}


}

\setcounter{framenumber}{\value{framenumbervorappendix}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user3285148 You're welcome!

Comment: Could you point out which lines in your preamble solve (3) specifically?  Thanks!

Comment: @nukeguy Basically the whole preamble deals with (3)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `\AtEndDocument...` line to

```
\pretocmd\appendix{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{nav}%
{\noexpand\headcommand{\noexpand\beamer@subsectionframes{\the\beamer@subsectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}}{}{}
```

then you will not get circles for the sections etc. in the appendix. Using [samcarter's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331755/how-to-exclude-backup-slides-from-numeration-and-outline#comment813129_331755) of `[noframenumbering]` you can avoid the title page getting a number without resorting to fiddling the counters.

However, I'm not altogether convinced I understand the aim here.

[image: fewer circles, numbers]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcount\beamer@subsectionstartframe
\beamer@subsectionstartframe=1
\apptocmd{\beamer@subsection}{\addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{%
      \protect\beamer@subsectionframes{\the\beamer@subsectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\beamer@subsection}{\beamer@subsectionstartframe=\c@framenumber\advance\beamer@subsectionstartframe by1\relax}{}{}
\pretocmd\appendix{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{nav}%
    {\noexpand\headcommand{\noexpand\beamer@subsectionframes{\the\beamer@subsectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}}{}{}
\def\beamer@startframeofsubsection{1}
\def\beamer@endframeofsubsection{1}
\def\beamer@subsectionframes#1#2{%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber<#1%
    \else%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber>#2%
    \else%
    \gdef\beamer@startframeofsubsection{#1}%
    \gdef\beamer@endframeofsubsection{#2}%
    \fi%
    \fi%
}
\newcommand\insertsubsectionstartframe{\beamer@startframeofsubsection}
\newcommand\insertsubsectionendframe{\beamer@endframeofsubsection}
\makeatother

\newcounter{subsectionframenumber}
\newcounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \parbox[b]{.4\textwidth}{
        \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead%
        \setcounter{subsectionframenumber}{1}
        \addtocounter{subsectionframenumber}{\insertframenumber}
        \addtocounter{subsectionframenumber}{-\insertsubsectionstartframe}
        \setcounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{1}
        \addtocounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{\insertsubsectionendframe}
        \addtocounter{totalsubsectionframenumber}{-\insertsubsectionstartframe}
        \ifnum\thesection>0%
        \foreach\x in {1,...,\thetotalsubsectionframenumber}{%
          \ifnum\x=\thesubsectionframenumber%
          \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}~%
          \else%
          \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}~%
          \fi%
        }%
        \fi%
      }%
      %\hfill\hyperlink{toc}{Outline}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=toc]
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{BLAH}
\subsection{sub1}

\begin{frame}{SLIDE1}\label{slide1}
  \hyperlink{appendix}{\beamergotobutton{More}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{SLIDE2}
\end{frame}

\appendix
\begin{frame}{Extensions}\label{appendix}
  \hyperlink{slide1}{\beamergotobutton{Back}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The circles do not match the number of slides

Comment: @user3285148 That was the point. As I understood the question at the time I answered, the frames should not get circles if in the appendix. (I guess you mean `frames` rather than `slides`.)

Comment: @user3285148 If that's not what you meant, you should have been clearer about whatever you did want.